# Iteratively compute the product where the function is dependent on the length.

Tags: polynomials

I'm working on an action selection system for a video game where characters decide upon which action to take by computing the *total estimated utility* for each action and picking that with the highest *estimated utility*.

Since actions may vary with the number of sensors they have, I've used the following to combine the *estimated utility* of each sensor reading to lower the penalty for having more things to consider.
$$\prod^{m}_{i=1}x_i+x_i(1-x_i)(1-1/m)$$ Where $m$ is the number of sensors, $x$ is the sensor result.

While this works, it requires $m$ to be known prior and thus I must store all sensor values if I wish to cache reads from sensors for actions that share a common set. Is it possible to move $m$ such that combining sensor values can be done iterativly without needing to know $m$ until the last sensor is known? If so, how?

The motivation behind this is going from having to store all common sensor values to just two values: the combined score before adjustment and the number of sensors involved.